# Spring Cloud Gateway embedded in a Spring Boot Rest API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to add Spring Cloud Gateway in my existing Spring Boot Rest API as embedded gateway.

I have a `@RestController` which has a `POST` method on this path `/api/employee/message`. I added below as Spring Cloud Gateway Configuration,

```
    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes().route(r -> r.path("/employee/**")
                .filters(f -> f.prefixPath("/api")
                        .modifyRequestBody(String.class, Hello.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                                (exchange, s) -> {
                                    uri = exchange.getRequest().getURI().toString();
                                    System.out.println("here");
                                    System.out.println(uri);
                                    return Mono.just(new Hello(s.toUpperCase()));
                                }))
                .uri(uri).id("employeeModule"))
                .build();
    }
```

When I call my `POST` rest endpoint `http://localhost:8080/employee/message`, it works, routes the call to `/api/employee/message` and modifies my request body as expected.

But now the problem is I can call `http://localhost:8080/api/employee/message` directly as well and that does not go through Spring Cloud Gateway configuration.

I have not found any examples for a embedded Spring Cloud Gateway in a Spring Boot Rest API application. Is there a way to use Spring Cloud Gateway as embedded?

More precisely, is it possible to somehow force a call to go through Spring Cloud Gateway even though there is a route defined in `@RestController`?

Something like, If I define a `@RestController` with path `/api/employee/message`, I should be able to define a Spring Cloud Gateway configuration which looks at `route.path = /api/employee/message` and apply the filters and then route the call back to the method defined in my `@RestController`.

If its not possible to have conflicting paths in one application, Is it possible to add a behavior such that users can not call `/api/employee/message` API directly. Otherwise users can always bypass what I configure in Spring Cloud Gateway and directly call the Controller endpoint.

Comment: Since it is in the same application you can't have conflicting paths. Only one can respond to `/api/employee/message`. You have to change one.

Comment: @spencergibb Thanks for your comment. That seems fair, in that case do you have any suggestion to somehow block direct API calls to `/api/employee/message` because even if I have different routes users can directly call `/api/employee/message` instead of  `/employee/message` which is configured in Spring Cloud Gateway. I have updated my question as well

Comment: I'm confused about the need for a gateway

Comment: @spencergibb I just want to rewrite path to add prefix or modify request body / header values and use other features of Spring Cloud Gateway, without having to introduce one more layer for my small micro service. Are you saying a gateway must be implemented outside of a microservice and should not be embedded?

Comment: The gateway would need to be the public api. You can use spring security to lock down the rest controller.

Comment: Hi rockyPeoplesChamp, where you able to find solution. I think i have similar problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75577216/unable-to-conditionally-route-from-kafka-listener-to-different-endpoints-via-spr